# How to know that Active Directory exists with only ip address?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

How to know that AD exists?

I have only ip address. I tried to use those methods:

```
if(DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://192.168.1.1"))
```

also

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.1.1")
```

but it didn't help.
I use LdapConnection right now, but I have a problem

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("192.168.1.1"));
                        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                        NetworkCredential credential =
        new NetworkCredential("a", '1");

                        connection.Credential = credential;

                        connection.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1000);
                        connection.Bind();
```

I'm getting 81 code and The LDAP unavailable.

Does somebody know is possible just to know is ip is correct and AD exists?

P.S. I use .NET 2

Comment: Are you running this from a machine on the domain or in the same domain as the domain controller?  Also is the user your running as in the domain or local to your computer for example?

Comment: I run from machine that not in same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (works with .NET 2.0 and does not need credentials):

```
...
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
...

string server = "192.168.1.1";

using (LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(server))
{
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;

    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(null, "(objectclass=*)",
          SearchScope.Base, "defaultNamingContext");

    SearchResponse result = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(request);

    if (result.Entries.Count == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Entries[0].Attributes["defaultNamingContext"][0]);
    }
}
```

It binds anonymously to the AD domain controller and retrieves the rootDSE entry. It displays the DN of the AD domain.

You can also query another attributes, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684291(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

AD can only be set to run on port 389 and/or 636. So if the port is open, it is a pretty good chance that LDAP is present.

Know if it is AD or not, would, typically, require you to have a valid LDAP account to BIND to the LDAP service.

You can perform a LDAP query against the LDAP service and [probably learn the VendorName](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determine%20LDAP%20Server%20Vendor).

Comment: OK but how to be with timeout?
Your idea is nice i can use this
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.1.1")
with credentials, but i should wait too long.

Comment: I get exception "server no operational" more then 3 seconds.

Comment: Try telnetting to port 389. If 389 is not listening, then it should reply with something like "Connection Refused". If it is listening, it will be something like connected to hostname.domain.com.